# How to count all indentical values in Column which belongs to Different Values in another column

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have a mysql database table which has 4 columns: ID, Date, SessionID, UserID(irrelevant here). Let's call them A, B, C,

What I can't figure out is how to count how many sessions has been booked to specific date.

For example something like this

```
      A  |      B     |  C
      ---|------------|------    
       1 | 2016-02-12 |  1  | 
       2 | 2016-02-12 |  1  | 
       3 | 2016-02-13 |  1  | 
       4 | 2016-02-12 |  5  | 
       5 | 2016-02-12 |  5  | 
       6 | 2016-02-13 |  2  | 
       7 | 2016-02-18 |  2  | 
       8 | 2016-02-19 |  3  |
```

So I want that my php code would output 
that for date 2016-02-12 I have 2 entries with value 1 and 2 entries with value 5.
For date 2016-02-13 I have one entrie with value 1 and one with value 2.

Comment: The column names are `A`, `B`, and `C` or `ID`, `Date`, and `SessionID`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work as you need

```
SELECT B AS date,COUNT(C) AS sessions FROM table GROUP BY B,C
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a simple `GROUP BY`.

```
SELECT Date, SessionID, COUNT(*)
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY Date, SessionID
```